# How can alfresco search services 2.0.2 search for the field value by exact match?

Tags: solr, alfresco, solr6, alfresco-search-services

In Alfresco Search Services 2.0, the behavior of the sign "=" has been changed, see [Exact Term Queries in Search Services 2.0](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-blog/exact-term-queries-in-search-services-2-0/ba-p/302200).

Now, if you write "=" in the query, the search will return all occurrences of this term, for example, you need to find "elephant", the search will return "pink elephant", "red elephant" etc. In version 1.4.0 the search will return the exact match. As now in version 2.0.2, you need to write a search query to return the exact match with the word "elephant", please tell me? **Tokenization cannot be turned off**

I need to find, for example, all elements that have cm:title="Elephant" with an exact match, the query cm:title="Elephant" results in returning elements with cm:title, such as "Pink Elephant", "Red Elephant", etc.

Comment: "_Tokenization cannot be turned off_", could you be more specific ? Exact _field match_ can only work on a _non-tokenized_ field.